# Can not insert php data to mysql using for()

Tags: php, mysql

i try to insert the data with php to mysql by checking the value if it exists then it will update if no then it will insert, but it fail i use for () what is wrong with my script?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $fieldA = $_POST['fieldA'];
    $fieldB = $_POST['fieldB'];
    $fieldC = $_POST['fieldC'];
    $fieldD = $_POST['fieldD'];

    if (empty($fieldA)) {
        echo 'fieldA cannot empty';
    } 
    else 
    {
        for ($i=1; $i<= $nomer; $i++) {
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb1 ".
                "WHERE fieldA = '$fieldA' ".
                "AND fieldB = '$fieldB' ".
                "AND fieldC = '$fieldC' ".
                "AND fieldD = '$fieldD'");
            $get1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
            $get2 = mysql_num_rows($query);

            if ($get2 != 0) {
                mysql_query("UPDATE tb1 SET kd_kelas = '2' ".
                    "WHERE fieldA = '$fieldA' ".
                    "AND fieldB = '$fieldB' ".
                    "AND fieldC = '$fieldC' ".
                    "AND fieldD = '$fieldD'");
            } else {

                mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb1(fieldA, fieldB, ".
                    "fieldC, fieldD) VALUES ".
                    "('$fieldA', '$fieldB', ".
                    "'$fieldC', '$fieldD')");
            }


        }
    }


    //re-direct
    $go = "mydata.php";
    redirect($go); 
}
```

Comment: What's th value of `$nomer` ? Try `var_dump($nomer)`

Comment: Instead of $get2 != 0 use $get2 > 0. Do you get anything for your select query  before checking the condition

Comment: @ObjectManipulator I take from the serial number id with $nomor ++;

Comment: @ChannaveerHakari yes the result is null but its supposedly though null he insert query but it is not

Comment: what is the purpose of loop?

Comment: @AnkurGarg to insert data or update data based on ID in select checklist

Comment: Is there any error in insert query of else condition, can you please use mysql_error() to check whats the error your getting and post here

Comment: there is no error but the data is not updated or to the insert to the database, is it because one of the 'where' there is wrong its value?
@ChannaveerHakari

Comment: @irwandwiyanto I am really finding difficult to read your language. Let me rephrase : Your not getting any error but the POST data values are coming null or empty. Is this what you meant

Comment: @irwandwiyanto can you please var_dump or print_r your $_POST so that I can get the good understanding of what values your getting in your POST request

Comment: @ChannaveerHakari, which I input only the value of each id. for example, fieldA = username, fieldB = age, fieldC = category, fieldD = status.

Answer (score 0):

All the methods related with `mysql_*` is deprecated now. Use `mysqli_*`.

And try this snippet:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['fieldA'])) {

    $fieldA = $_POST['fieldA'];
    $fieldB = $_POST['fieldB'];
    $fieldC = $_POST['fieldC'];
    $fieldD = $_POST['fieldD'];

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $nomer; $i++) {
        $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM tb1 WHERE fieldA = '%s' AND fieldB = '%s' AND fieldC = '%s' AND fieldD = '%s'",
            $fieldA, $fieldB, $fieldC, $fieldD);
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $updateSql = sprintf("UPDATE tb1 SET kd_kelas = '2' WHERE fieldA = '%s' AND fieldB = '%s' AND fieldC = '%s' AND fieldD = '%s'",
                $fieldA, $fieldB, $fieldC, $fieldD);
            mysqli_query($link, $updateSql);
        }
        else {
            $insertSql = sprintf("INSERT INTO tb1(fieldA, fieldB,fieldC, fieldD) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s')", $fieldA,
                $fieldB, $fieldC, $fieldD);
            mysqli_query($link, $insertSql);
        }
    }

    //re-direct
    $go = "mydata.php";
    redirect($go);
}
```

here `$link` is the connection string

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'database');
```

Comment: I use php version 5.6 does mysql not support anymore and must use mysqli?